# hadoop fs -lsr hdfs://localhost:9000 not working

Tags: hadoop

i am new to learning hdfs and have single node hadoop(version 2.2.0) set up over centos box.

after start-all command i am trying to run some of the hdfs commands but below mentioned is not working.

```
    bin/hadoop fs -lsr hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name
```

while this command is working

```
    bin/hadoop fs -lsr file:///tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name
```

this is my core-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
 <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>localhost:9001</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
<property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>1</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

telnet with localhost 9000 is working while telnet with x.x.x.x 9000 is not working also.

Can anyone tell me pls. where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 8):

HDFS is a filesystem, so use it as a filesystem:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
hadoop fs -ls /some/path/inside/hdfs
```

I also suggest you to use only fully qualified names for hosts in your configuration files. Simply said, don't use localhost.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I created a directory using hadoop mkdir command which is diplaying using fs -ls command but copyFromLocal is not displaying me the file with -lsr option. Any idea pls ?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but please check the paths. If you create a directory like this **'/somedir'** it will be created in root directory **'/'**, but if you create it with just **'somedir'** then it will be created in your HDFS home directory: **'/home/your_user/somedir'**. The same is true for **-ls** and **-copyFromLocal** (by the way **-put** is shorter)